# Centos 6.4 install only showing 160G of 192G installed ram, dmesg shows all 16x16G sticks

Tags: linux, centos, memory

Any ideas why? Same sever with ubuntu 12.04 shows 192G properly.

With centos 6.4 (64 bit):

[image: one]

with Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit):

[image: two]

I put the mem=193447M in the kernel section of /boot/grub/grub.conf to no avail.

dmidecode shows, with regards to memory, two 96G banks and 16x16G sticks:

dmesg shows all 16 sticks but before that reports: (System RAM: 164864MB)

Comment: here is the output from dmidecode: http://pastie.org/private/xyqcxi4npw0sdebim92jg#

Comment: What hardware are these sticks stuck in?

Comment: Supermicro board with dual L5520 xeon's

Comment: I have to say, I wish I had the problem of only having 160GB of RAM. :-p

Comment: Here is the output from lshw:
http://pastie.org/private/bxt0wn1ywnltdkmrjirh3q

Comment: If you look at lshw - it shows memory bank 2 -> 5 and 6 are "empty" but they are filled in the bios...

Comment: Supermicro gear :(

Comment: It works fine with ubuntu... it's a centos problem. motherboard has the most recent firmware already, X8DTU-F (firmware 2.1c).

Comment: I see that the system is running them at 800mhz though and they are 1066mhz sticks... might point to a memory profile issue.

Comment: 16 x 16 = 256. Something's wrong if you're only expecting 192 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically swapped all the DIMMs around and rebooted, came up with 192G.

Haven't seen that happen before, but systems with many DIMMs are much more susceptible to this.

Comment: That's a lot of RAM for such a low-end CPU! I'm glad reseating the DIMMs fixed it.